# Why does this not cause a stack overflow? And where is a global vector stored (stack or heap)?

Tags: c++, stack, overflow, global

I thought the local_array would be placed on the stack and thus overflow (?).
The global_array doesn't overflow either so I assume there are on the heap, right?

```
vector <int> global_array; //if I fill this array: is it the stack or the heap ?

int main() {
vector <int> local_array; 
for (int i=0; i < 100000000; i++) local_array.push_back(1); // no stack overflow!
for (int i=0; i < 100000000; i++) global_array.push_back(1); // no stack overflow!
int array[1000000]; // stack overflow.
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` always uses dynamic allocation ("the heap").

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment has already said. std::vector use a dynamically allocated array to store their elements, so both of your vectors are stored on the heap and therefore no stack overflow.